SQLAlchemy keeps joining a 3rd table
I am following the fastapi course from freecodecamp(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA). I am trying to join 2 tables, Vote and Post. The model for vote:-
class Vote(Base):
    __tablename__="votes"
    user_id=Column(Integer,
                   ForeignKey("users.id",ondelete="Cascade"),
                   primary_key=True)
    post_id=Column(Integer,
                   ForeignKey("posts.id",ondelete="Cascade"),
                   primary> _key=True)

The model for Post:-
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__="posts"
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    title=Column(String,nullable=False)
    content=Column(String,nullable=False)
    published=Column(Boolean,server_default='True',nullable=False)
    created_at=Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),nullable=False,
                      server_default=text("now()"))
    user_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey("users.id",ondelete="CASCADE"),
                                      nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User",foreign_keys=user_id,lazy=False)  

The query I am using to join Post and Vote is:-
results=db.query(models.Post,func.count(models.Vote.post_id).label("votes")).join(
        models.Vote,
        models.Vote.post_id==models.Post.id,isouter=True).group_by(models.Post.id)

However, when I print the sql part of this query I get:-
SELECT posts.id AS posts_id
    ,posts.title AS posts_title
    ,posts.content AS posts_content
    ,posts.published AS posts_published
    ,posts.created_at AS posts_created_at
    ,posts.user_id AS posts_user_id
    ,count(votes.post_id) AS votes
    ,users_1.id AS users_1_id
    ,users_1.email AS users_1_email
    ,users_1.password AS users_1_password
    ,users_1.created_at AS users_1_created_at
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = posts.user_id
GROUP BY posts.id

Can anyone help me out on this ? Users table should not be even called on this.
   
   
I've looked up this issue everywhere and I am unable to find a solution, someone suggested that it could be because users_id is a foreign key, that that table is being joined automatically.

As noted in the docs, lazy=False is a synonym for lazy="joined"
